# Method Not Allowed when using url for in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How to pass parameters inside an URL for in javascript? 
I have a case like this:

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function () {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
    console.log(user_id);
    $('#modal-form').attr('action', "{{ url_for('admin.delete_user' , id="' + user_id +'" ) }}");
 });
```

`user_id` variable has a value `56f52ea551d72027711157d6`

If I do like this I get `Method Not Allowed because` the URL looks like this:

```
/admin/users/delete/%27%20+%20user_id%20+%27
```

How should I pass arguments in this part?

```
$('#modal-form').attr('action', "{{ url_for('admin.delete_user' , id="' + user_id +'" ) }}");
```

please somebody help me?

Edit:
The method that I use in route admin.delete_user in python is:

```
mod_admin.add_url_rule( '/users/delete/<string:id>', methods=['GET'])
def delete_user(self, id):
    mongo.db.users.remove({'_id': ObjectId(id)})
    return redirect(url_for('admin.users'))
```

And the modal popup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></h4>
    </div>
    <form id="modal-form" action=" "  method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Are you sure?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-style" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-filter-apply btn-style" >Yes</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the template `{{ }}` is evaluated by jinja and converted to a string *before* the browser ever sees it, you don't need to concatenate all of the strings like you have shown. The `id` parameter should be passed as a standard keyword arguments.

```
$('#modal-form').attr('action', "{{ url_for('admin.delete_user' , id=user_id|string) }}");
```

You will also need to allow `POST` requests to the specified URL by updating this

```
mod_admin.add_url_rule( '/users/delete/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

**UPDATE**

Because `user_id` is actually defined in *javascript*, this is an issue because `user_id` is not accessible to jinja. To get around this, you will need to create your URL in this way:

```
$('#modal-form').attr('action', "{{ url_for('admin.delete_user') }}" + user_id);
```

Comment: if I use this i get this url /admin/users/delete/ not the right one /admin/users/delete/56f52ea551d72027711157d6

Comment: @EgzEst Then you will need to show your view. I'm assuming you defined your route incorrectly.

Comment: @EgzEst Do you have a route decorator? I updated my answer with an example

Comment: @EgzEst Ok it looks like it's expecting `id` to be a string and I'm assuming `user_id` is a number. I have updated my answer to cast it as a string.

Comment: @EgzEst Also just made an update because you will need to allow POST requests within your route

Comment: thank you for your help  but now I get this error:  jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError UndefinedError: 'str' is undefined,  ..

Comment: @EgzEst Sorry about that, You have to use `user_id|string` within jinja. Updated.

Comment: Still in action i get this url :action="/admin/users/delete/"  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107345/discussion-between-suever-and-egzest).